# style of selected item in lisbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a list box which is bound to a list of strings.

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
                 Height="130"
                 Background="Black" BorderThickness="0"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanoItemTemplate}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}">

            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Height="110"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

and in VM I have:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Images
{
  get { return _images; }
}

public string SelectedImage
{
  get { return _selectedImage; }
  set
  {
    _selectedImage = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedImage");
  }
}
```

When I populate Image list and select one of them in listbox by clicking on it, I can get it in SelectedImage and the system works well.

When I click on an item on list box, it shows as selected I ListBox (Blue colour on white background).

If I set the SelectedImage in code to an item which is in image list, that item is selected on list, but the colour is different (it is white on white background).

How can I change the style of selectedImage when I select them via code to be the same as when user select them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListBox` will only highlight blue when it has user focus, otherwise it uses a different brush

When the ListBox is focused it used `SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey`, and when unfocused it uses `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`

So you could set the `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` to the `SystemColors.HighlightColor`, this will keep it blue in and out of focus.

Example:

```
<ListBox >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

### Edit:

For **.NET4.0 and below** you may have to use `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` instead of `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`

```
<ListBox >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```